# Woocommerce add downloadable files by PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to add downloadable files in Woocommerce by PHP by this code:

```
$pd_object = new WC_Product_Download();

$pd_object->set_id($attachment_id);
$pd_object->set_name($attachment['name']);
$pd_object->set_file($attachment['file']);

$productw = wc_get_product($productw_id);

$downloadsw = $productw->get_downloads();

$downloadsw[$attachment_id] = $pd_object;

// Set the complete downloads array in the product
$productw->set_downloads($downloadsw);
$productw->save();
```

However, the file did not added in downloadable files in edit page of the product. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I didn't get any error but the files wasn't added in the "downloadable files" when I tried to edit the product page. However, the "_downloadable_files" seems to be correctly edited in my database.

Comment: woocommerce already has a downloadable product option, so try using this instead

Comment: This link might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747596/add-downloads-in-woocommerce-downloadable-product-programmatically

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas I exactly used that code but didn't work for me

Comment: What were the errors? You should provide what you have tried when using that code

Comment: @TobiasTheel I edited my question