# Access downloadable data from WooCommerce downloadable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, download, product

I'm trying to fetch the WooCommerce products meta data using `$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );` I'm getting the product price and all the other values the products are downloadable WooCommerce products, I want to fetch the following data:

[image]

Whenever i try to fetch `$product->downloads->id` or `$product->downloads->file` i'm getting null in return. Please tell me what i'm doing wrong over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access all product downloads from a downloadable product you will use `WC_Product` [`get_downloads()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_downloads).

It will give you an array of `WC_Product_Download` Objects which protected properties are accessible through [`WC_Product_Download` available methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Download.html) *(since WooCommerce 3)*:

```
// Optional - Get the WC_Product object from the product ID
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

$output = []; // Initializing

if ( $product->is_downloadable() ) {
    // Loop through WC_Product_Download objects
    foreach( $product->get_downloads() as $key_download_id => $download ) {

        ## Using WC_Product_Download methods (since WooCommerce 3)

        $download_name = $download->get_name(); // File label name
        $download_link = $download->get_file(); // File Url
        $download_id   = $download->get_id(); // File Id (same as $key_download_id)
        $download_type = $download->get_file_type(); // File type
        $download_ext  = $download->get_file_extension(); // File extension

        ## Using array properties (backward compatibility with previous WooCommerce versions)

        // $download_name = $download['name']; // File label name
        // $download_link = $download['file']; // File Url
        // $download_id   = $download['id']; // File Id (same as $key_download_id)

        $output[$download_id] = '<a href="'.$download_link.'">'.$download_name.'</a>';
    }
    // Output example
    echo implode('<br>', $output);
}
```

Related answers:

- [Add downloads in Woocommerce downloadable product programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747596/add-downloads-in-woocommerce-downloadable-product-programmatically/47748411#47748411)
- [Add programmatically a downloadable file to Woocommerce products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954367/add-programmatically-a-downloadable-file-to-woocommerce-products/52955772#52955772)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the download link, try:

```
$downloads = $product->get_downloads();
```

This should return an array, so you can use it for example like:

```
foreach( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
    echo '<a href="' . $download["file"] . '">Download File</a>';
}
```